# AngularJS - can't get array from $http to show in ng-repeat, only individual item e.g. [0]

Tags: angularjs

I'm VERY new at angular (so, apologies if the language I'm using is wrong) and I'm trying to pull in info from the Stack Overflow API. The data is pulling in when I specify an individual item, however I want to pull in the top 10 questions into an ng-repeat and it's returning undefined. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Scope:

```
var loadFeed = angular.module('loadFeed', []);

loadFeed.controller('feedController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {

$scope.questions = [];

$http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions?pagesize=10&order=desc&sort=votes&tagged=angular&site=stackoverflow'
}).then(function(feed) {

    console.log('success');
    console.log(feed);

    //$scope.questions = feed.data.items;   -- This doesnt work?
    $scope.questions = feed.data.items[0];  // This is working but obviously only shows the first item

    console.log($scope.questions); // Returns data
    console.log($scope.questions.title); // Returns title of question


},function(error) {
    console.log('error');
    console.log(error);
});

}]);
```

HTML:

```
<div id="container" ng-app="loadFeed" ng-controller="feedController">

        <h1><span>Top 10 </span>Angular Questions</h1>

        <div id="feed">
            <ng-repeat="question in questions" ng-show="!questions.length">
                <div class="question-list">
                    <h2><a href="{{questions.link}}" title="{{questions.title}}" target="_blank">{{questions.title}}</a></h2>  
                    <div class="details"><div class="owner"><div class="image"><a href="{{questions.owner.profile_image}}" title="View {{questions.owner.display_name}}" target="_blank"><img src=""/></a></div>
                <a class="name" href="{{questions.owner.link}}" title="View {{questions.owner.display_name}}" target="_blank">{{questions.owner.display_name}}</a><span class="rep" title="Reputation Score"><span class="fa fa-star-o"></span> {{questions.owner.reputation}}</span></div>
                <div class="created" title="Date asked"><span class="fa fa-calendar"></span>{{questions.creation_date}}</div></div><div class="is-answered">{{questions.answer_count}} answers<span class="triangle"></span></div>
                </div>  


            </ng-repeat>

        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe  `ng-show` is the issue.

It says `ng-show="!questions.length"`, which would only show if the `length` is falsy (`0` or `null` or `undefined` etc), because it has a "not" operator `!`.

It works for `items[0]` because it has no `length`, so `!questions.length` becomes truthy.

It does not work for the actual array with non-zero items in it because `length` exists and is higher than 0, so `!questions.length` is falsy.

You probably mean `!!questions.length` (note that's `!!` not just `!`).

**Also**, inside the `ng-repeat` tag (in the child tags), you should be using `question` not `questions`.

Like:

```
<div class="question-list">
  <div ng-repeat="question in questions" ng-show="!!questions.length">
    <h2>
      <a ng-href="{{question.link}}" title="{{question.title}}" target="_blank">{{question.title}}</a>
    </h2>
    <div class="details">
      <div class="owner">
        <div class="image">
          <a ng-href="{{question.owner.profile_image}}" title="View {{question.owner.display_name}}" target="_blank">
            <img src="" />
          </a>
        </div>
        <a class="name" ng-href="{{question.owner.link}}" title="View {{question.owner.display_name}}" target="_blank">{{question.owner.display_name}}</a>
        <span class="rep" title="Reputation Score">
          <span class="fa fa-star-o"></span> {{question.owner.reputation}}</span>
      </div>
      <div class="created" title="Date asked">
        <span class="fa fa-calendar"></span>{{question.creation_date}}</div>
    </div>
    <div class="is-answered">{{question.answer_count}} answers
      <span class="triangle"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

P.S.

I changed all `<a href="{{...}}"` to `<a ng-href="{{...}}"` in the above code. [Here's the documentation on why](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHref). Also used `ng-repeat` as an attribute just again to be writing [like the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat).

Comment: It's working! Thank you so much for this and the explanations! It definitely makes more sense now.

Comment: Great news! I'd appreciate it if you click the tick to the left of this answer too to let others know that this is the correct answer to your question. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You can specify `limitTo` filter in `ng-repeat` itself by doing :

```
<div ng-repeat="question in questions | limitTo:10" ng-show="questions.length > 0">
```

Note : You are using angular directive i.e. ng-repeat as html tag which does not work. Change your `ng-show="!questions.length"` to `ng-show="questions.length > 0"`

In this way, you can set all questions in `$scope.questions` and display the limited number of questions by using `limitTo` filter.

Looking in your code, you need to make some changes :

In your controller, update to this code :

```
$scope.questions = feed.data.items;
```

In your HTML,

```
<div ng-repeat="question in questions | limitTo:10" ng-show="questions.length > 0">
        <div class="question-list">
            <h2><a href="{{question.link}}" title="{{question.title}}" target="_blank">{{question.title}}</a></h2>  
            <div class="details"><div class="owner"><div class="image"><a href="{{question.owner.profile_image}}" title="View {{question.owner.display_name}}" target="_blank"><img src=""/></a></div>
            <a class="name" href="{{question.owner.link}}" title="View {{question.owner.display_name}}" target="_blank">{{question.owner.display_name}}</a><span class="rep" title="Reputation Score"><span class="fa fa-star-o"></span> {{question.owner.reputation}}</span></div>
            <div class="created" title="Date asked"><span class="fa fa-calendar"></span>{{question.creation_date}}</div></div><div class="is-answered">{{question.answer_count}} answers<span class="triangle"></span></div>
        </div>     
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I've made these updates and unfortunately when changing the code to $scope.questions = feed.data.items; the values in the ng-repeat are blank. I can't work out why. It will only return a value if an individual item, e.g. [0] is set.

Comment: @Laura : It's because you are using angular directive i.e. ng-repeat as as html tag which does not work. You need to assign angular directive in html tag. I've updated my answer. Now, it's working